# How to position the destination of the link generated by hyperref in the center of the page?

Tags: hyperref, positioning

I'm using the package `hyperref`, and it works perfectly. But I want that when I click in link generated by the package, the destination of the link, the figure or the equation, stays centralized on the screen, not at the extremes. How could I do this?

Answer (score 4):

For floats (`figure`s and `table`s) the `hypcap` package (same author as `hyperref`) is useful. It takes care that the hyperlink jumps to the beginning of the float, not the caption of it. However, this doesn't guarantee that the whole float is displayed. Also, this most likely doesn't do anything for equations.

Simply load the `hypcap` package after `hyperref`.

---

In general it would also be possible to generate a hypertarget which displays a certain rectangle, like the whole figure or equation when used as a link target. For this the `pdfview` option must be set to `FitR` and the position of two diagonal corners must be known. These could be acquired using the `zref-abspos` package (again same author as `hyperref` :-) ).